# Deep Javascript or jQuery conversion of JSON object to query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, regex, urlencode

I need help getting around an issue with jQuery's $.param() deficiency of not working deep enough, and it's leaving some of the deeper JSON with things like `%5D` and so on.

Not that this is a PayEezy eCommerce API matter, but their sandbox API requires a query string that looks like the following:

`https://api-cert.payeezy.com/v1/securitytokens?apikey=FAKEZdp9nJrKu46wX9evGNnRbGL38W6I&js_security_key=js-FAKE79a767d3fea1611ae66e1c6bfd2af8f879a767d3fea1&callback=respondPEZ&auth=true&ta_token=NOIW&type=FDToken&currency=USD&credit_card.cardholder_name=John+Doe&credit_card.card_number=4111111111111111&credit_card.exp_date=1218&credit_card.cvv=100&credit_card.type=visa&billing_address.street=&billing_address.city=&billing_address.state_province=&billing_address.zip_postal_code=&billing_address.country=&billing_address.email=&billing_address.phone.type=&billing_address.phone.number=`

As you look at that, I want you to notice things like `billing_address.state` rather than `billing_address[state]`, and rather than `billing_address%5Bstate%5D`. I need it a special way for PayEezy.

So, I created this JSON object like so in Javascript:

```
var o = {
    apikey: 'FAKEZdp9nJrKu46wX9evGNnRbGL38W6I',
    js_security_key: 'js-FAKE79a767d3fea1611ae66e1c6bfd2af8f879a767d3fea1',
    callback: 'respondPEZ',
    auth: true,
    ta_token: 'NOIW',
    type: 'FDToken',
    currency: 'USD',                
    credit_card: {
        type: 'visa',
        cardholder_name: 'John Doe',
        card_number: '4111111111111111',
        exp_date: '1218',
        cvv: '100'
    },
    billing_address: {
        street: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        state_province: undefined,
        zip_postal_code: undefined,
        country: undefined,
        email: undefined,
        phone: {
            type: undefined,
            number: undefined
        }
    }
};
```

Now, when you run that through jQuery's $.param(), you get a result that's not close enough on the query string:

`apikey=FAKEZdp9nJrKu46wX9evGNnRbGL38W6I&js_security_key=js-FAKE79a767d3fea1611ae66e1c6bfd2af8f879a767d3fea1&callback=respondPEZ&auth=true&ta_token=NOIW&type=FDToken&currency=USD&credit_card%5Btype%5D=visa&credit_card%5Bcardholder_name%5D=John+Doe&credit_card%5Bcard_number%5D=4111111111111111&credit_card%5Bexp_date%5D=12%2F18&credit_card%5Bcvv%5D=100&billing_address%5Bstreet%5D=&billing_address%5Bcity%5D=&billing_address%5Bstate_province%5D=&billing_address%5Bzip_postal_code%5D=&billing_address%5Bcountry%5D=&billing_address%5Bemail%5D=&billing_address%5Bphone%5D%5Btype%5D=&billing_address%5Bphone%5D%5Bnumber%5D=`

See those `%5D` and `%5B`? Those are undesirable, and not what PayEezy wants in their API.

So, I managed to get closer to fixing the problem by doing this:

```
var s = decodeURIComponent($.param(o,false));
```

But then found I could fix it even more by doing this:

```
var s = decodeURIComponent($.param(o,false))
    .replace(/\]\=/g,'=')
    .replace(/\]\[/g,'.')
    .replace(/\[/g,'.');
```

My question to you is -- is there a more polished way to convert the object-embedded JSON object into a more URL-friendly query string that doesn't include the square brackets and does include the dot notation, and perhaps in less lines of code than the regex replace technique that I settled on? For instance, is there already some functions in jQuery or Javascript that, when combined, handle this rather nicely that I'm not aware of?

Comment: make your own serializer. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/serialize.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made my own recursive serializer. Hopefully it works as requested.

The function will loop through all properties of an object. If the value is an object, it will call itself and passes in a `"breadcrum"`. A `breadcrum` is just a "path" of properties that the function has taken to get to where it is at. For example, if we're looking at the phone type in the billing address, the `breadcrum` passed to the function would be `billing_address.phone.`.

If the value is not an object, then it just appends itself to the breadcrum and again appends itself to the query string.

If the value is `undefined`, I've just set this to an empty string.

```js
var o = {
    apikey: 'FAKEZdp9nJrKu46wX9evGNnRbGL38W6I',
    js_security_key: 'js-FAKE79a767d3fea1611ae66e1c6bfd2af8f879a767d3fea1',
    callback: 'respondPEZ',
    auth: true,
    ta_token: 'NOIW',
    type: 'FDToken',
    currency: 'USD',                
    credit_card: {
        type: 'visa',
        cardholder_name: 'John Doe',
        card_number: '4111111111111111',
        exp_date: '1218',
        cvv: '100'
    },
    billing_address: {
        street: undefined,
        city: undefined,
        state_province: undefined,
        zip_postal_code: undefined,
        country: undefined,
        email: undefined,
        phone: {
            type: undefined,
            number: undefined
        }
    }
};

function convertToQueryString(object, currentBreadcrum = '') {
    var queryString = '';
    
    for (var property in object) {
        var potentialObject = object[property];
        
        if (typeof potentialObject === 'undefined') {
            potentialObject = '';
        } // set undefined values to an empty string
        
        if (typeof potentialObject === 'object') {
            queryString += convertToQueryString(potentialObject, currentBreadcrum + property + '.');
        } else {
            if (currentBreadcrum === '' && queryString === '') { // don't prepend an '&' if it's the first item in the query string
                queryString += currentBreadcrum + property + '=' + potentialObject;
            } else {
                queryString += '&' + currentBreadcrum + property + '=' + potentialObject;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return queryString;
}

console.log(convertToQueryString(o));
```